# How can i create table & insert values in sqlite with data types like Date,Enum,blob

Tags: android, json, sqlite, enums

This is my `DBHandler` class.

If you check  my create statement it has data types like enum,blob,date.And in my `ArrayList<Items> getAllItems()` while i am doing "`items.setItem_metric_type`"

This is the error I'm getting

```
ERROR IS:CHANGE 1ST PARAMETER ENM TO INT.
```

And yeah i'm getting data from a server.

```
    public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements ItemsListener{
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_NAME ="Items.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME ="Item";
    private static final String item_number="item_number";
    private static final String item_ean="item_ean";
    private static final String item_desc="item_desc";
    private static final String item_name="item_name";
    private static final String item_metric_type="item_metric_type";
    private static final String item_favorite="item_favorite";
    private static final String item_common_quantity="item_common_quantity";
    private static final String item_common_SP="item_common_SP";
    private static final String Item_metric_value="Item_metric_value";
    private static final String item_SP="item_ SP";
    private static final String item_company="item_company";
    private static final String item_brand="item_brand";
    private static final String Item_product_line="Item_product_line";
    private static final String item_category="item_category";
    private static final String Item_type="Item_type";
    private static final String item_mrp="item_mrp";
    private static final String mfg_date="mfg_date";
    private static final String exp_date="exp_date";
    private static final String Item_vat="Item_vat";
    private static final String batch_id="batch_id";
    private static final String Item_in_multiples="Item_in_multiples";
    private static final String Item_image_selected="Item_image_selected";
    private static final String last_modified_time="last_modified_time";
    private static final String last_modified_by="last_modified_by";
    private static final String Item_active="Item_active";
    private static final String Item_auto_added="Item_auto_added";
    String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" (item_number INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,item_ean INTEGER,item_desc TEXT NOT   NULL,item_name TEXT NOT NULL,item_metric_type INTEGER NOT   NULL,item_favorite BOOLEAN,item_common_quantity FLOAT,item_common_SP FLOAT,Item_metric_value FLOAT,item_SP FLOAT,item_company TEXT,item_brand   TEXT,Item_product_line TEXT,item_category INTEGER, Item_type    INTEGER,item_mrp FLOAT,mfg_date DATE,exp_date DATE,Item_vat FLOAT,batch_id INTEGER,Item_in_multiples BOOLEAN,Item_image_selected BLOB,last_modified_time DATETIME,last_modified_by INTEGER,Item_active BOOLEAN,Item_auto_added ENUM)";
    String DROP_TABLE="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
    public DBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context,DB_NAME,null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
    public void addItems(Items items) {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(item_number, items.getItem_number());
        values.put(item_ean, items.getItem_ean());
        values.put(item_desc, items.getItem_desc());
        values.put(item_name, items.getItem_name());
        values.put(item_metric_type,    String.valueOf(items.getItem_metric_type()));
        values.put(item_favorite,items.getItem_favorite());
           values.put(item_common_quantity,items.getItem_common_quantity());
        values.put(item_common_SP,items.getItem_common_sp());
        values.put(Item_metric_value,items.getItem_metric_value());
        values.put(item_SP,items.getItem_sp());
        values.put(item_company,items.getItem_company());
        values.put(item_brand,items.getItem_brand());
        values.put(Item_product_line,items.getItem_product_line());
        values.put(item_category,items.getItem_category());
        values.put(Item_type, String.valueOf(items.getItem_type()));
        values.put(item_mrp,items.getItem_mrp());
        values.put(mfg_date, String.valueOf(items.getMfg_date()));
        values.put(exp_date, String.valueOf(items.getExp_date()));
        values.put(Item_vat,items.getItem_vat());
        values.put(batch_id,items.getBatch_id());
        values.put(Item_in_multiples,items.getItem_in_multiples());
        values.put(Item_image_selected,   String.valueOf(items.getItem_image_selected()));
        values.put(last_modified_time,   String.valueOf(items.getLast_modified_time()));
        values.put(last_modified_by,items.getLast_modified_by());
        values.put(Item_active,items.getItem_active());
        values.put(Item_auto_added, String.valueOf(items.getItem_auto_added()));
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        db.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Problem inserting",e+"");
    }

}

@Override
    public ArrayList<Items> getAllItems() {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<Items> itemList=null;
    try{
        itemList=new ArrayList<Items>();
        String QUERY="SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(QUERY,null);
        if (!cursor.isLast())
        {
            while (cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                Items items=new Items();
                items.setItem_number(cursor.getInt(0));
                items.setItem_ean(cursor.getInt(1));
                items.setItem_desc(cursor.getString(2));
                items.setItem_name(cursor.getString(3));
                //items.setItem_metric_type(cursor.getInt(4));
                //items.setItem_favorite(cursor.getString(5));
                items.setItem_common_quantity(cursor.getFloat(5));
                items.setItem_common_sp(cursor.getFloat(6));
                items.setItem_brand(cursor.getString(7));
                items.setItem_product_line(cursor.getString(8));
                items.setItem_category(cursor.getInt(9));
                items.setItem_type(cursor.getInt(10));
                items.setItem_mrp(cursor.getFloat(11));
                items.setMfg_date(cursor.getInt(12));
                items.setItem_vat(cursor.getFloat(13));
                items.setBatch_id(cursor.getInt(14));
                items.setItem_in_multiples(cursor.getString(15));
                items.setItem_image_selected(cursor.getInt(16));
                //items.setLast_modified_time(cursor.getColumnName(17));
                items.setLast_modified_by(cursor.getInt(18));
                itemList.add(items);
            }
        }
        db.close();
      }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("error displaying",e+"");
      }
      return itemList;
   }

    @Override
    public int getItemsCount() {
    int num=0;
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    try {
        String query="SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);
        num=cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        return num;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("in getcount",e+"");
    }
    return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int    newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);

    }
    }
```

Comment: Which specific statement gets the error? What is that data?

Comment: @CL. items.setItem_metric_type(cursor.getInt(4));
items.setItem_favorite(cursor.getString(5));
items.setItem_type(cursor.getInt(10));
items.setItem_mrp(cursor.getFloat(11));
items.setItem_in_multiples(cursor.getString(15)); items.setItem_image_selected(cursor.getInt(16)); items.setLast_modified_time(cursor.getColumnName(17));

All these lines have errors...
Data is of types are different. like enum,boolean,date,float.

Comment: @CL. So wherever there are boolean or date or enum, i'm getting error.
Data types like string,int,float are working fine.

Comment: @CL. if you look in my addItmes 
values.put(item_metric_type,String.valueOf(items.getItem_metric_type()));
I was asked to wrap it with String.

Comment: @CL. could you please let me know what's wrong with my code???

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has a limited [set of data types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storageclasses).

Boolean values are directly supported by the `ContentValues` class. To read data from a cursor, compare the number against zero, or just call [cursorRowToContentValues()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#cursorRowToContentValues(android.database.Cursor,%20android.content.ContentValues)) before (this also makes reading values using the column name easier).

You have to choose how to store enumeration values in the database; you can use either strings or numbers. The best way to handle this is to add methods to the enum to convert from/to the database type.

SQLite's built-in date/time functions support several [formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), but Java code often uses another format (used internally by Java): milliseconds since 1970.
Whatever format you choose, your code must convert from/to the database format, with, e.g., `Date.getTime()` or your own conversion functions.